# Hair particle bald spots

Tags: particles, hair

This part of my model has bald patches. The hairs are facing inwards. I've looked up the issue and most people advised to try flipping/recalculating the normals, trying to apply all transforms to the mesh, or just add more hairs on top of the bald spot. I tried all of that, but nothing is working...

[image]

Comment: disable deflect emitter and try to comb again, if this somewhat works I can post a more detailed answer. If not, please share a wireframe screenshot from the side.

Comment: If you enter Weight Paint mode, do any of the (affected) areas look different?

Comment: Disabling deflect emitter and brushing from the inside out worked! Thanks